# illegal instruction running node.js in pentium2

Tags: node.js

after unpack my correct arch packgas in linux; and exec node

it say: Illegal Instruction and not run

There is and strace: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd4073637df7672dfff1

an there is my cat /proc/cpuinfo: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/21e11d8f6e4d5c6adeb0

Comment: Maybe try compiling from source? Perhaps the package that you got doesn't work properly on P2s.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you tell me what dependency I need in order to compile?

Comment: Just check out the node repo and then do the standard `./configure`  and install any dependencies that it can't find, then `make` and `make install`.